# Validate Select2 in Yii2 via AJAX

Tags: ajax, validation, yii2, jquery-select2

I have Yii2 application which uses the Kartik plugin to initialize Select2 dropdowns in forms.

I have one particular Select2 which uses AJAX call to get the data for the drop down options.

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'court_house_id', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true, 'selectors' => ['input' => '#' . $id . "-court-house"],'template' => FormHelper::GenerateFieldTemplate([6])])
->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'options' => ['id' => $id . "-court-house", 'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Search court house...')],
    'hashVarLoadPosition' => \yii\web\View::POS_READY,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'dropdownParent' => new JsExpression("$('#$modalWindowId')"),
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 2,
        'language' => [
            'errorLoading' => new JsExpression("function () { return '" . Yii::t('app', 'Search...') . "'; }"),
        ],
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => app\components\UrlMaker::link('data/court-house-list'),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(courthouse) { return courthouse.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (courthouse) { return courthouse.text;}'),
]])
->label(Yii::t('app', 'Court House'), ['class' => FormHelper::GenerateLabelClassTemplate([3])]);
?>
```

Intentionally pasting all of the code, although most of it is irrelevant I would assume.

I have this loaded in multiple dynamically created forms thus all the strange ids and selectors. However, the form has different dropdown which controls whether some of the fields are shown (and required) or not. This particular field above is only shown in one of the scenarios which all the other variations of the form do not have it. So the model has the following validation:

```
[['court_house_id', 'staff'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_ONE],
```

By the way `staff` is just a regular text field and everything works for it.

In order to change the scenario, I have the following line in the ***view*** with the form:

```
<?php $model->scenario = \app\models\MyModel::SCENARIO_ONE; ?>
```

The problem is that when I submit the form empty, the `staff` field gets marked in red as invalid but the court house is marked in green as valid although it is empty.

If I go into the model and remove the `'on' => self::SCENARIO_ONE` part then everything works as expected - on empty submit the court house field also lights up in red but that would be a problem for the rest of my scenarios where this field is not needed.

Any ideas what might be causing the problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: can you paste your complete set of rules that you have in the model. try adding all the relevant portions of the problem like the action that is related to the problem too where you are loading the view

Comment: maybe not sure but you must set the scenario before you call the validate/save method which means that you should set the scenario in the controller action rather in the view

Comment: I think it has something to do with `'enableAjaxValidation' => true`. If this is the **only** item in the form then the AJAX validation is not working as if this code is not existing but if there are other items in the form which do have this piece of code, then all AJAX validations trigger properly. Need to investigate more.

Comment: you said this input is dependent on the scenario, if the scenario is set before the validate/save call and it is the only input in the form, it SHOULD work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the scenario in controller before calling save() method, for example

```
$model = new MyModel(['scenario' => MyModel::SCENARIO_ONE])
```