# Upload image in yii2 activeform

Tags: php, image, yii2, upload

I need a simple image upload with a local copy in my project folder: web/uploads/project+project_id+random_unique_key. I've tried with this code but I guess there is conflict between two submit buttons, I just want that the first calls actionUpload() check if the chosen file is an image and then gives me a success/error message and the second calls actionCreate() saving the model in the database.
My problem is that click on second button does nothing and click on first gives the error 'image cannot be blank'.

views/project/create

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'link')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>

<button>Upload</button>

<br></br>

<?= $form->field($model, 'is_deleted')->checkbox() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

ProjectController

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new Project();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->image->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->image->baseName . '.' . $model->image->extension);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Project();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $model->setCreated_at();
        if($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Project(model)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'description', 'link', 'image', 'is_deleted'], 'required'],
        [['created_at'], 'safe'],
        [['is_deleted'], 'boolean'],
        [['title', 'description', 'link', 'image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to read the documentation . how to upload a file https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload

Comment: and what is the problem you are having? never mentioned it, apart from it you should use ajax based uploads for this purpose , can use kartik Fileinput extension

Comment: I edited the question but can anyone help me instead of pasting the documentation link?

Comment: try this plugin for yii2, will solve you many problems https://github.com/gomonkey/yii2-easy-uploader

Comment: merge the 2 actions, and make your life easier , dont do it this way you would have to control many things

Answer (score 0):

Make AJAX request on button click (you can use Jquery)

```
$('form button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    if(formData.get('Project[image]')){ 
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/upload',
            data: formData,
            success: function(error){
                if(error){
                     $(form).yiiActiveForm('updateAttribute', 'project-image', [error]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
})'
```

Controller

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new Project();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

        if ($model->validate('image')) {
            $model->image->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->image->baseName . '.' . $model->image->extension);
        }
    }

    return $model->getFirstError('image');
}
```

Rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'description', 'link', 'is_deleted'], 'required'],
        [['created_at'], 'safe'],
        [['is_deleted'], 'boolean'],
        [['title', 'description', 'link'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
    ];
}
```

if you don't want to write own js to init ajax request, you can install Kartik File Input widget.

Example:

```
$form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::class,[
            'options' => [
                'accept' => 'image/*',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'layoutTemplates' => [
                    'main1' =>'{preview}' .
                        '<div class="kv-upload-progress kv-hidden"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>' .
                        '<div class="input-group {class}">' .
                        '  {caption}' .
                        '  <div class="input-group-btn">' .
                        '    {upload}' .
                        '    {browse}' .
                        '  </div>' .
                        '</div>',
                    'main2' => '{preview}<div class="kv-upload-progress hide"></div>{upload}{browse}',
                ],
                'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/upload']),
                'maxFileCount' => 1,
                'autoReplace' => true,
                'showPreview' => false,
                'showCaption' => true,
                'showRemove' => false,
                'showUpload' => true,
            ]
        ])
```

It will register all js code for you to make ajax.

Comment: Thank you but idk how to use ajax and prefer implement this with php.

Comment: If you don't know how to use ajax, you can use http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput it will register js ajax code for you

Comment: i notice that you add answers by reading the comments under the question, its the second time today, first one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457958/validate-select2-in-yii2-via-ajax/54458798#54458798), secondly you dont need to bind the ajax call when you are using the fileInput extension, you can enable AJAX uploads by setting the `uploadUrl` property in `pluginOptions`. You can also pass extra data to your upload URL via `uploadExtraData`, please add answers that you think you know you can answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in this situation, your form is not sending file to server. Add enctype option to your form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
]); ?>
```